# Just how cheap are computations with local variables?

Tags: solidity, gas, local-variables

Beginner question: I have a function that needs to make many (potentially thousands or hundreds of thousands) of computations. Naturally I'm worried that the gas cost will make this unusable. I've managed to make it so that almost all of the computations only use local variables. My question is whether computations using local variables are cheap enough that something like this can be a practical strategy with reasonable gas costs.

Comment: You can take a look at this page for the opcode costs https://github.com/wolflo/evm-opcodes. Usually arithmetic operators are cheap, the more expensive are large memory allocations, using persisten storage, interacting with other contracts.

Comment: Yes, you are right at your end, using local variables would do save gas cost. There are contracts which have done heavy calculations. Moreover, try using gas optimization techniques in your code. Try to make your code as short as possible, thereby reducing opcodes. Eg. can be use efficient packing of your variables.

Comment: Thanks, these comments are helpful